# How to create an options page in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to create an options page and I am wondering how to save the settings on that page.
I know how to create a normal page with a form and usually each field in that form is a column in the database.

But for the options page, each setting (for ex. layout, colors, fonts, etc), should either be per row or stored as an array in the database.

Does anybody ever did this?

EDIT to clarify

I would like to have a db table as followed:

```
id | setting_name | setting_value
---|--------------|--------------
1  | page_bg      | #FFFFFF
2  | page_width   | full
```

And the form should be something like:

```
<form>
    <label for="page_bg">Page background color</label>
    <input id="page_bg" name="page_bg" type="text" />
    <label for="page_width">Page Layout</label>
    <select id="page_width" name="page_width">
        <option value>Select layout</option>
        <option value="full">Full</option>
        <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I have an options page with all settings already shown as a form (similar to a theme in wordpress).

Answer (score 0):

This seems like very simply a form for multiple entities. Use a naming scheme like

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('settings.0.setting_name', ['value' => 'layout']);
echo $this->Form->input('settings.0.setting_value');
echo $this->Form->hidden('settings.1.setting_name', ['value' => 'color']);
echo $this->Form->input('settings.1.setting_value');
```

If you are editing existing settings instead of creating new ones, then replace the `setting_name` fields with `id`.

In your controller, you'll do `patchEntities()` and `saveMany()`.

You might also look at [this plugin](https://github.com/cakemanager/cakephp-settings) for either inspiration, or for use in your project.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for yours btw. I have updated my question.

Comment: Do you really need to use field names like that, or does it just suit your personal preferences? If the latter, I'd suggest that it's a lot easier to adjust your preferences than it is write code to match them.

Comment: I always use field names in that way, so I know easily what that are for when retrieving them from db. At the moment I have no idea on how to accomplice this. If you have any suggestions, that would be great.

Comment: Conventions are useful, until they get in the way of writing concise code. I think that's the case here. I think that you'd be better served by letting that particular preference go in this case. If you follow something like the code I posted (I've updated it with your column names), the name fields show you what the accompanying value is for, instead of the input name itself.